# How many people do we need to get the classic 25-man raid guild achievements?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

I believe that we need 8 members to do the old 10-man raids for the guild achievements.  I seem to vaguely recall a mention that 25-man would only need 8 people as well but I'm not sure if that made it out of beta.

Also, do 40-man raids still exist?  How many people do we need for those?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 8 guild members in the raid for all pre-cataclysm raid achievements in 10, 20, and 25 man zones. 40 man raids require 10 guild members. 5 man dungeon achievements require 4.

And, with the exception of Naxx 40, yes, all of the old 40 man zones (MC, BWL, and AQ40) are still in the game.

Comment: Does it require 8 people to get the personal achievement also? or can someone solo/partner MC for the personal achievements?

Comment: No, my answer refers exclusively to guild achievements. You can solo things if you just want the points for yourself.

Comment: This isn't true - it takes 10 guild members to get credit for a 40-man raid.

Comment: Blue post on the subject mirrored here: http://www.wowblues.com/us/guild-achievements-for-classic-dungeonsraids-26560501163.htm. It does seem that though only 8 are now required for 25-man, 10 are still needed for 40-mans.